# Getting grunt error on sails lift

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I am getting this error on sails lift.

Sails version : **v0.10.0-rc11**

```
error: Grunt :: module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/mandeep/freelance/hellos/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
info:
```

I have tried uninstalling grunt globally and then re-installing but its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like something got corrupted in your Sails install.  In your project directory do:

```
npm uninstall sails
npm cache clear
npm install sails
```

That should fix it.  A more scorched-earth approach would be:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clear
npm install
```

To make sure all of your dependencies are up to date.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer did not work for me; uninstalling, clearing the cache, and reinstalling did not force sails to add the necessary dependency to its node_modules (I think because I have grunt-cli installed globally).  Instead I had to go into `my_project_directory/node_modules/sails` and run `npm install grunt-cli`

See https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2059 for more explanation and hopefully some feedback or a bugfix from the sails team.

Comment: global install of grunt-cli should not cause any issues. I faced this issue again where the above method did not work. Then I had to remove grunt-cli from my package.json and then removed all npm packages and reinstalled. Then it worked