# Not found error on browser after sails lift,

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am creating a new app with "sails new" command. Upon running sails lift, I am getting a "Not Found"(404) error on the browser. I have sails installed locally & here are my node & sails version info

```
vsnag@like:~/sails/node_modules$ sails --version
0.10.5
vsnag@like:~/sails/node_modules$ node --version
v0.10.32
```

The sails lift with verbose options gives me this

```
vsnag@like:~/sails/app$ sails lift --verbose

info: Starting app...

warn: Cannot read package.json in the current directory (/home/vsnag/sails/app)
warn: Are you sure this is a Sails app?
warn:
warn: The package.json in the current directory does not list Sails as a dependency...
warn: Are you sure `/home/vsnag/sails/app` is a Sails app?
warn:
verbose: Setting Node environment...
verbose: Please run `npm install coffee-script` to use coffescript (skipping for now)
verbose: moduleloader hook loaded successfully.
......
....
error:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.
......
...
verbose: Sending 404 ("Not Found") response
verbose: res.notFound() :: Could not locate view for error page (sending JSON instead).  Details:  Could not render view "404".  Tried locating view file @ "/home/vsnag/sails/app/views/404". Layout configured as "layout.ejs", so tried using layout @ "/home/vsnag/sails/app/views/layout.ejs")
```

I tried the solution suggested in [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453807/getting-grunt-error-on-sails-lift/), but of no use.

When I compare the anatomy of a sails App mentioned in [sails docs](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/anatomy/myApp) & my app they don't seem to match

```
vsnag@like:~/sails/app$ ls -la
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 5 vsnag vsnag 4096 Oct  9 21:36 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 vsnag vsnag 4096 Oct 10 18:54 ..
drwxrwxr-x 7 vsnag vsnag 4096 Oct  9 21:36 api
drwxrwxr-x 4 vsnag vsnag 4096 Oct  9 21:36 config
drwxrwxr-x 2 vsnag vsnag 4096 Oct  9 21:36 views
```

I am missing the Gruntfile.js, README, app.js, .gitignore, package.json, .sailsrc files.

Any suggestions what might be the problem? or any setting that I am missing...

Answer (score 0):

make a empty new sails app (in your home-folder) with:

```
 $> sails new myapp
```

than copy your api, views and config in this "myapp"-folder and run `sails lift` again

Comment: I tried this, not much of different. Problem is after  "sails new" the Gruntfile.js, README, app.js, .gitignore, package.json, .sailsrc are not copied/created at all, ideally which should have happened part of the sails new command.

Answer (score 0):

Check your importer.less

I accidently included something that is not in there (a missing folder) and after fixing it, it worked. (:

If it doesn't check your pipeline.js to see if you have injected the correct files.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the `sails new` command with npm because I installed it locally instead of globally. I got the not found and a 404. When I installed it globally, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For me I was not inside project folder,

After creating news sails project

**cd** into project folder

eg:

```
> sail new todo-app
> cd todo-app
```

Then run `sails lift`